# How to edit webpack to use SCSS in React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I created a new React app with create-react-app (using React ver. 16.6.3). Now I want to use SCSS for my components. So first I ran the eject script. Then in webpack.config.dev.js I did the following edit:

```
{
   test: cssRegex,
   exclude: cssModuleRegex,
   use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
        }),
}
```

I also installed node-sass package.

Then I created my Test .scss file:

```
.Test {
  background-color: gold;
  .Header {
    color: lighten(purple, 20%);
  }
}
```

And my Test component with importing the .scss file

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './test.scss';

const Test = (props) => (
  <div className={style.Test}>
    This is div1
    <div className={style.Header}>Div 2</div>
  </div>
);

export default Test;
```

That didn't work and I didn't see any styling. I tried to import the .scss directly and use it:

```
import './test.scss';

...
<div className='Test'>
  This is div1
  <div className={style.Header}>Div 2</div>
</div>
...
```

That did work and I saw the styling on the div with className='Test'.

I tried to change the webpack as follows:

```
const CSSModuleLoader = {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
    minimize: true
  }
}

const CSSLoader = {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: false,
    sourceMap: true,
minimize: true
  }
}

const postCSSLoader = {
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    ident: 'postcss',
    sourceMap: true,
    plugins: () => [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['>1%', 'last 4 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'not ie < 9']
      })
    ]
  }
}

...

{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
  use: ['style-loader', CSSLoader, postCSSLoader, 'sass-loader']
},
{
  test: /\.module\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    CSSModuleLoader,
    postCSSLoader,
    'sass-loader',
  ]
},
```

At first I got an `autoprefixer not defined` error. I imported it with `const autoprefixer = require('style-loader')` - that made this error disappear, though I'm still not convinced that was the correct require and correct fix.

But then I got the following error:

`Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use should be one of these:
   non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, ident?, query? } | function | [non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, ident?, query? }]
   -> Modifiers applied to the module when rule is matched
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use should be an object.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use[1] should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use[1] should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[0].use[1] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
      object { loader?, options?, ident?, query? }`

Don't know how to deal with that...

How do I configure webpack to either immediately compile .scss to .css in the same directory (that way I can import .css and use it regularly with `style.Class`) or to use the .scss import in my file in the same manner and later compile it to .css for production?

Comment: Did you already check https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader ?

Comment: @phng Yes, it was one of the things I tried. Though I didn't get any errors, it still didn't compile into .css file. Unless I didn't do something right...

Answer (score 0):

Please use below rules in webpack file and remove extra code.

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove extra code"? I tried your suggestion as is, and got the following 'Failed to compile' error in my test.scss: `.Test {
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in work-path\my-project\src\components\test.scss (line 1, column 1)`

Comment: What he means with extra code is you should remove your own code you tried to compile sass with and replace it with the official example. Alternatively check out this postCSS + Sass example configuration: https://github.com/mrmartineau/webpack-recipes/blob/master/css/sass/webpack.config.babel.js When I compare both config files (yours and the github one of mrmartineau) I guess you integrated PostCSS wrong.

Comment: @lgal I don't see the requirement of postCSSLoader in "use:" array. You can refer this file https://github.com/guptagovind/react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.dev.js

Comment: I tried everything and still no luck. I'm getting the .scss styles, but they're not compiled into .css. The postcss-loader is loaded in getStyleLoaders method. I know I didn't copy-paste it here, but here's a link to pastebin with my current webpack.config.dev: https://pastebin.com/HuX84Cnc  What am I missing here?